Raster re-projected with gdalwarp not projecting correctly
I inherited an application that uses an unconventional CRS. I am trying to reproject a raster image 'SA_Cities_2011_NLCD_C.tif' to a new file 'SA_Cities_2011_NLCD_C_Projected.tif' using gdalwarp. I am getting the target CRS from a vector shapefile 'Sensitivity_Analysis_Cities_Projected.prj' which does display correctly with QGIS. I am using the following command...
gdalwarp -t_srs "Sensitivity_Analysis_Cities_Projected.prj" -overwrite "SA_Cities_2011_NLCD_C.tif" "SA_Cities_2011_NLCD_C_Projected.tif"

After adding "SA_Cities_2011_NLCD_C_Projected.tif" as a layer to QGIS, there is a definite offset indicating to me the raster was not reprojected correctly.

The CRS from the 'Sensitivity_Analysis_Cities_Projected.prj' file is valid, but the datum is "D_unknown"...
INFO: Open of `Sensitivity_Analysis_Cities_Projected.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: Sensitivity_Analysis_Cities_Projected
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2024-03-29
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 150
Extent: (-2289119.216035, 600724.892611) - (2052736.188521, 2814981.672370)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCRS["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_GRS_1980_IUGG_1980",
        DATUM["D_unknown",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Albers Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",23,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-96,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",29.3,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",45.5,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
OBJECTID: Integer64 (10.0)
GEOID10: String (7.0)
NAME10: String (100.0)
NAMELSAD10: String (100.0)
STATE: String (254.0)
STATEA: Integer64 (10.0)
COUNTYA: String (254.0)
COUSUBA: String (254.0)
PLACE: String (254.0)
PLACEA: Integer64 (10.0)
NAME: String (254.0)
Population: Integer64 (10.0)
Housing: Integer64 (10.0)
Pl_Uniq_id: Integer64 (10.0)
CityAreaAc: Real (19.11)
KBTU: Integer64 (10.0)
ecoRegion: String (50.0)
EPA_CSO: Integer64 (10.0)
Krissy_CSO: Integer64 (10.0)
Y_coor: Real (13.11)
StateName: String (4.0)
GISJOIN: String (20.0)
CSO_StormW: Integer (5.0)
Valid_ST: Integer (5.0)

The CRS of 'SA_Cities_2011_NLCD_C_Projected.tif' retrieved using gdalinfo is...
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: SA_Cities_2011_NLCD_C_Projected.tif
Size is 145126, 74054
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_GRS_1980_IUGG_1980",
        DATUM["D_unknown",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["Albers Equal Area",
        METHOD["Albers Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",23,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-96,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",29.3,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",45.5,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-2289271.445518341381103,2815758.488579935394228)
Pixel Size = (29.920043904522057,-29.920043904522057)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-2289271.446, 2815758.489) (125d35'19.43"W, 45d 5'51.78"N)
Lower Left  (-2289271.446,  600059.557) (118d52'49.86"W, 25d57'46.64"N)
Upper Right ( 2052904.846, 2815758.489) ( 69d18' 2.13"W, 45d43' 0.44"N)
Lower Right ( 2052904.846,  600059.557) ( 75d24'18.04"W, 26d26'57.86"N)
Center      ( -118183.300, 1707909.023) ( 97d21'58.60"W, 38d23'18.42"N)
Band 1 Block=145126x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=255

Any ideas as to why this is not reprojecting correctly?

Does the original shapefile and the original raster file match correctly with some other software? What software? What is the CRS of the original "SA_Cities_2011_NLCD_C.tif"?

Yes, it was an economic model developed by another person no longer with the company. The original projection is ESRI:102039.
